When filtering events in SSMS XEvent Profiler what is the difference between Contains and Like filters?
In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), when filtering events in XEvent Profiler, what is the difference between the Contains operator and the Like operator?  I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.
Here is the Filters dialog for the XEvent Profiler, showing the list of possible comparison operators, including Contains and Like:


What about the documentation, CONTAINS & LIKE, did you find unclear?

@ThomA X events profiler isn't using full text indexing or full text search predicates

My assumption would be that LIKE accepts wildcards and has the same semantics as LIKE in a query whereas CONTAINS is just looking for the literal substring

Removing the filter shows the previously hidden events so it is just something implemented in SSMS rather than anything done by the server

@ThomA, those links are for T-SQL CONTAINS and LIKE.  As far as I can tell the XEvent Profiler LIKE filter operator, at least, doesn't behave like the T-SQL LIKE.  If I have a filter string like '%FROM MyTable% it's not picking it up (and, in fact, filters out all rows, leaving 0 rows in the result set).

I couldn't find this documented.
I expected that LIKE would behave as the TSQL LIKE keyword and support % as a wildcard. In reality this does not work.
From looking at the decompiled FilterBinaryExpression class in Microsoft.SqlServer.XEventStorage.dll it looks like it produces a Regex by processing the string as follows (so supports * and ? as wildcards for arbitrary length strings and single characters respectively - analogous to % and _ in the SQL Like syntax)
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      stringBuilder.Append("^");
      foreach (char ch in wildcard)
      {
        switch (ch)
        {
          case '*':
            stringBuilder.Append(".*");
            break;
          case '?':
            stringBuilder.Append(".");
            break;
          default:
            stringBuilder.Append(Regex.Escape(ch.ToString()));
            break;
        }
      }
      stringBuilder.Append("$");
      this.wildcardRegex = new Regex(stringBuilder.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

The usage of this regex then checks
wildcardRegex.IsMatch(str)

Whereas the Contains filter just checks
str.IndexOf(this.value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1

So does a case insensitive check if the string contains the literal substring.

Thanks for your efforts in getting to the bottom of this.
